# Product of an array of infinity by an array of zeros gives me an array of NaN

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen

I want to multiply an array of infinity by another array of zeros using Eigen library:

```
Eigen::ArrayXd a(2); a << INFINITY, INFINITY;
Eigen::ArrayXd b(2); b << 0.000, 0.000;
```

The result gives me:

```
std::cout<a*b<<std::endl;
```

The output is

```
nan
nan
```

Why I don't get a vector of zeros?

Comment: TL;DR: It's complicated ;)

Comment: This has nothing to do with vectors. It’s simply a rule of IEEE floating point: infinity * 0 is NaN. After all, what else could it be?